# Validation Error Temple does not seem at first time

Tags: wpf, validation

I write simple Validation code for wpf . There is text box . If I enter invalid value or textbox is empty then Validation Error Temple appears on windows.  This is okay. It works very well.

But I use this code another project.  I use ribbon menu. When I clicked ribbon button in ribbon menu, My page is navigated in frame but Validation Error temple does not seem at page.  If a enter a value and then delete then Temple appears.  I don't Understand. What does same code behave

Comment: You want to force the validation as soon as the control is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Your validation code is getting triggered when property text of your text box get changed. Some how on frame navigation property changed event is not firing on page load event. I will be able to help more if you provide your validation logic and the way you are binding the text box.

Comment: triggred event is "propertychanged" . Normally it is work fine in simple example project. I include code to my reall project. My project start with mainwindows . There is ribbon menü at mainwindows.When ı clicked ribbonbutton. Textbox that ı have told above is appers . But not work at first time.

Comment: can you provide the code you used for navigating between pages. i.e. frame.navigate(URI of page) or frame.navigate(Object of page)

Comment: GroupSayfası gs=new GroupSayfası();                                                                  private void GrupEkleB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)                                                                            GroupEkleB is ribbonbutton
        {
            
            frame1.NavigationService.Navigate(gs);
            
                
        }